# Function in R to select the row with highest value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with the columns for city name and vote percentage along with other fields. Each city has more than 1 candidate and each candidate has their vote share so the city name column has multiple rows for 1 city. There is no column for the winner. So, i want to add 1 column for that so that i can run analysis on that.

I need help in writing a function which goes through vote share of candidates for a particular city (multiple rows) and then assign a value of 1 for the guy with highest vote share.

Image of the dataframe:

[image]

There are nearly 5000 rows for over 400 cities.

Comment: Very hard to help without a sample of usable data. Please edit your question to include the output of `dput(head(YOUR_DATA_FRAME, 20))`. Generally speaking, the **dplyr** or **DT** packages are well suited to these types of per-group operations.

Comment: You meant `data.table` not `DT` .

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one line solution using base R -

```
df <- data.frame(City = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
                         Candidate = letters[23:26],
                         Votes = sample.int(1000, 4), stringsAsFactors = F)

df$Flag <- ave(df$Votes, df$City, FUN = function(x) x == max(x))

#      City Candidate Votes Flag
# 1    A         w    14    0
# 2    A         x   412    1
# 3    B         y    50    0
# 4    B         z   969    1
```

Comment: Always nice to see base R!

Answer (score 1):

Very easy with `data.table` as it groups so well via `by`.  A reproducible example:

```
R> suppressMessages(library(data.table))
R> set.seed(123)        # make it reproducible
R> N <- 100             # arbitrary
R> x <- data.table(city=sample(LETTERS, N, replace=TRUE), vote=runif(N, 0, 100))
R> setkey(x, city)      # for sorted display and faster access, but not required
R> head(x, 12)
    city    vote
 1:    A 52.1136
 2:    A 74.6568
 3:    B 89.0350
 4:    B 95.4091
 5:    B 84.7453
 6:    C 72.0596
 7:    C 35.3905
 8:    C 58.1750
 9:    C 59.4343
10:    C 65.9230
11:    D 69.0007
12:    D 31.1702
R>
```

Now that we have the data, the actual task is a one-liner:

```
R> x[, high := vote==max(vote), by=city]   # assign vote==max(vote) by city
R>
R> head(x, 12)
    city    vote  high
 1:    A 52.1136 FALSE
 2:    A 74.6568  TRUE
 3:    B 89.0350 FALSE
 4:    B 95.4091  TRUE
 5:    B 84.7453 FALSE
 6:    C 72.0596  TRUE
 7:    C 35.3905 FALSE
 8:    C 58.1750 FALSE
 9:    C 59.4343 FALSE
10:    C 65.9230 FALSE
11:    D 69.0007 FALSE
12:    D 31.1702 FALSE
R>
```

This uses a boolean as the result of the 'is it the maximum value' comparison, if you really need an integer you can of course cast it:

```
R> x[, high:=NULL]  # remove first as we change type
R> x[, high := as.integer(vote==max(vote)), by=city]
R> head(x,12)
    city    vote high
 1:    A 52.1136    0
 2:    A 74.6568    1
 3:    B 89.0350    0
 4:    B 95.4091    1
 5:    B 84.7453    0
 6:    C 72.0596    1
 7:    C 35.3905    0
 8:    C 58.1750    0
 9:    C 59.4343    0
10:    C 65.9230    0
11:    D 69.0007    0
12:    D 31.1702    0
R>
```

*Edit:* My expression was overly complicated, and has been simplified.

Comment: Glad to know. Please feel free to "upvote" (click on up-triangle) and/or "accept" (click on tickmark only you as the person asking see) as this is how StackOverflow signals value in answers.